# Simple Unification Theory

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Every equation I seem to find that calculates the electrostatic force between a point and a hollow sphere approximates the hollow sphere as a point.  But, if I use a simple spreadsheet numerical approximation the force in the point to sphere numerical approximation is different from the force in the conventional point to point equation.  Further, if I use the same approach to graph the interaction between the protons and electron shells in a two hydrogen system, the force graphs as a Lennard Jones over distance.

Assuming distances d1 and d2 are identical in the (awesome) drawing below and the charges on points 1, 2 and the sphere are identical the electrostatic force using Coulomb’s Law between points 1 and 2 does not equal the electrostatic force between point 1 and the charged sphere, contrary to what I am reading.

[image]

Based on the diagram below and a spreadsheet of, say 360, points on the circle produces a force different to the standard Q1Q2/r^2

[image]

The approximation is a Riemann sum below

[image]

Which is the integral;

[image]

The integral resolves to the following corrected equation for the force between a point and a sphere;

[image]

Which matches the numerical approximation to a lot of decimal places.  And this is where it gets weird.  If you use that same equation to model four different forces in Hydrogen gas (below) and pull the atoms apart the force over distance is a Lennard Jones curve.

[image]

Using a Hydrogen radius of 53pm the corrected point to sphere calculation yields a net electrostatic force that varies over distance forming a Lennard Jones curve predicting a stable nuclear separation distance of 170pm.   And, because the force has a tail in the LJ curve the same corrected equation continues to produce a weak electrostatic force somewhat larger than gravity at great distance.  The discrepancy is probably my values for radii, or perhaps simulating an electron as a hollow sphere.  But the point is the close forces seem about right and the exact same equation yields a weak force at great distance.

I can write more but will wait for feedback.  Or, if someone can point me in the direction of a numerical approximation of the classical Newtonian shell theory.  I'm trying to understand the actual requirement for bands and why an infinitely thin band, or a line, wasn't used in the first place.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: "Every equation I seem to find that calculates the electrostatic force between a point and a hollow sphere approximates the hollow sphere as a point." This is called Gauss Theorem and it is exact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but I think there is a mistake in your calculations: When you write "The approximation is a Riemann sum below", you neglect the vertical part:
$F=\frac{kq_1q_2}{s^2}$, where $s$ is the distance between a part of the shell with coordinates $(r\sin(\theta),rcos(\theta))$ and the test particle located at $(0,d)$. Therefore the averaged-out force is

$$\bar{F}=kq_1q_2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{d^2+(d-r\cos(\theta))^2}=kq_1q_2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{d^2-2rd\cos(\theta)}=\frac{d^2}{d^2-r^2}F.$$

Comment: The vertical parts can be ignored because they cancel each other out when moving across the top of the circle against moving back across the bottom of the circle.  You can leave them in but they have no net effect.